# Column average in database from a .txt file

Tags: python, csv

Here is the question:

Write a program that computes the average learning coverage (the second column, labeled LC) and the highest Unique learner (the third column, labeled UL). 
Both should be computed only for the period from June 2018 through May 2019. 
Save the results in the variables mean_LC and max_UL.

The content of the .txt file is as below:

```
Date,LC,UL
1-01-2018,20045,687
1-02-2018,4536,67
1-03-2018,6783,209
1-04-2018,3465,2896
1-05-2018,456,27
1-06-2018,3458,986
1-07-2018,6895,678
1-08-2018,5678,345
1-09-2018,4576,654
1-10-2018,456,98
1-11-2018,456,8
1-12-2018,456,789
1-01-2019,876,98
1-02-2019,3468,924
1-03-2019,46758,973
1-04-2019,678,345
1-05-2019,345,90
1-06-2019,34,42
1-07-2019,35,929
1-08-2019,243,931
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I am not going anywhere with it! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Importing the pandas package.
import pandas as pd

# Reading the CSV formatted file using read_csv function.
df = pd.read_csv('content.txt')

# retraining only the data from 2018 June to 2019 May
#Filter your dataset here
df = df[ (df['Date'] >= '1-06-2018' ) & (df['Date']  <= '1-05-2019') ]

# Using the predefined pandas mean function to find the mean.
#To find average/ mean of column
mean_LC = df['LC'].mean()

# Using the predefined pandas max value function to find the Max value
#To find the Max UL
max_UL = df['UL'].max()
```

This link will give you an idea of how the code is actually working : https://www.learnpython.org/en/Pandas_Basics

Comment: Nice we did some homework and to me the comments are good. But, as the person asking did not get anywhere before, please kindly add some documentation helping a newbie to present the homework as original ;-)

Comment: Yep, Exactly. Should've done that first I guess. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Thank you @high-octane for the answer. But was just wondering, is there another way of solving the problem. Without using Pandas or for that matter, without importing a module ?

Answer (score 1):

Cracked it !!

```
with open("LearningData.txt","r") as fileref:
    lines = fileref.read().split()
    UL_list = []
    sum = 0
for line in lines[6:18]:
    sum += float(line.split(",")[1])
    UL_list.append(line.split(",")[2])
    max_UL = UL_list[0]
    for i in UL_list:
        if i> max_UL:
            max_UL=int(i)

mean_LC = sum/12
print(mean_LC)
print(max_UL)
```